# POCO how to send XML data?

Tags: c++, http-post, poco-libraries

In my project,I have encountered a serious problem which program can't receive data and then crash.
these are my code :

```
HTTPClientSession s("x.x.x.x",8000);
HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST);
std::ostream& send = s.sendRequest(request);
std::string body = "<a> xml </a>";
request.setContentLength( body.length() );
send << body <<std::flush;
HTTPResponse response;
std::istream& res = s.receiveResponse(response);
StreamCopier::copyStream(res, std::cout);
```

After I run it,when my program received data from server,it crashed and throw

```
Poco::Net::messageException
```

.Oh,my god!
I traced it into internal code of POCO , finding :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
```

is my data sended property in VS2005. 
At the same time ,Poco find the last letter of `<!DOCTYPE` is `E`which is not a space ,so it throw the exception.
Do any one encouter the case? who can help me ?Thank you ,very much!!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sending data almost the same way. There's just one difference in my code.

```
request.setContentType("text/xml; charset=utf-8");
```

According to the source code of the Poco library, exception 'Poco::Net::MessageException' is raised because of malformed response from http server.

Comment: I add these codes into my project,but nothing happens.@Denis Novikov

Comment: ,can you give me a sample to introduce what you think,thanks!

Comment: When I try Your code with google.com (ip="173.194.32.164") I don't get any exception. The same happens when I try with server written by myself with Poco::Net::HTTPServerSession.

But some servers does not return HTTP header in response. And that is the reason for the MessageException.

Comment: You may replace lines 
`HTTPResponse response;
std::istream& res = s.receiveResponse(response);`
with code:
`Poco::Net::HTTPInputStream res(s);`
And You'll see full response (including headers) from server. You need to `#include <Poco/Net/HTTPStream.h>` into your source.

Comment: ,as what you just said,the POCO's server designed by myself gives me a header "HTTP/1.1 200 OK".On the other hand,the server  that cause the problem gives me "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">" .Then ,to this problem,is there any method to solve it?

Comment: The server that gives you "<!DOCTYPE ...>" message works incorrect. In the first line of response it should return status-line (ie, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"). If you want to work with messages that doesn't contain status-line and headers, you should parse response youself (e.g. use HTTPInputStream).

Comment: Then ,Using HTTPInputStream to get many `std::string`s,how can I get them from the stream ? What i think is `std::list`,but not work.

Comment: ,Thank you very much ,you are the best.I have an other question,How can I build OpenSSL with POCO? Now,I wanna use HTTPSClientSession,but no OpenSSL.can you give me a link??

Comment: To split istream into `string`s you can use `getline` method.

Comment: I haven't worked with HTTPS yet. That's why I cannot answer your question about OpenSSL.

Comment: ,After I sended data to Server,to use `session.receiveResponse(response)` is hardcode for receiving.I want to use a `callback` function to do it.For example,the Server send response to client,then call the `callback` automaticlly.How can i do it?the sample in POCO didn't complete it like what I want.

Comment: I don't see any callback handling in documentation for `HTTPClientSession` class. I think You should implement `callback` yourself. (i.e. create new class that agregates `HTTPClientSession`).

Comment: you're a great helper!@Denis Novikov.As what you said,do I have to  use `HTTPCliensSession::receiveResponse` to receive data ?? In Qt,I can use `Signal&Slot mechanism` to receive them which is easy to be understood for me,but POCO isn't.

Comment: ,I have another question.I question that 
`HTTPCliensSession::receiveResponse` is called by programmer in `synchronous`,but itself executes in `asynchronous` mode.Do you think so?

Comment: Yes, you do! You have to use `receiveResponse`.

Comment: I think You're rigth about `synchronous` and `asynchronous` mode.

Comment: ,I encountered a exception called `SSL Exception`,what can I do then? 
`msg = "error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol"` .Did you have seen it?